# Efficient environment for machine or deep learning in Python

Tags: machine-learning, python, deep-learning

I am getting very frustrated working with either Google Colab or Azure notebooks (they are very slow and glitchy). Usually, I work with Jupyter notebooks to perform Machine Learning or Deep Learning tasks in Python.

Does anyone have any recommendations for a truly good performing alternative? It does not matter if it is free or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try Kaggle, they have kernels with GPUs (free but limited 9 hours runtime I think)

Google cloud is currently beta testing jupyter notebooks on their infrastructure. You do not need to spawn your own compute instance, or even start a Docker: you have your jupyter kernel in your browser in a matter of minutes (https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform-notebooks/). There runtime is illimited but if your connection is glitchy the notebook might disconnect and you can loose your data.

But as a rule of thumb if your runtime is several hours, it might be better to prototype on a subset in notebook and then train on your full dataset in command line.